# Ursina Entity Being clicked in a place where it shouldn't be

Tags: python, debugging, raycasting, ursina

Somehow an entity is being clicked (i.e its on_click command is executing) when certain empty spaces around it are clicked. After moving a piece to a new space on the board the code initially works as intended, however after selecting the piece then deselecting it, it somehow becomes  possible to select the piece the piece by clicking above it or on the sides on it. (This issue is a little hard to explain in text so I took a brief [screenrecording](https://youtu.be/x7AtPiEUe2I) to showcase it and hopefully make the issue a little clearer). Strangely enough though when moving the cursor down below the piece before hovering over the other sides the issue disappears.
(Oh yea, idk if its important but the project I'm working on is a 3 dimensional chess board).

If you want to recreate the issue or just look at what I've written, I've got the code across two files

gameSetUp

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
import time
class intVec3():
        def __init__(Self, x, y, z):
             Self.x = x
             Self.y = y
             Self.z = z
        def __repr__(Self):
             return (Self.x, Self.y, Self.z)
        def __str__(Self):
             return str(Self.x)+" , " + str(Self.y) + " , " + str(Self.z)
def changeAlpha(model, alpha):
        model.alpha = (alpha)
def blank():
        print("Change in mouse")
class Space():
        def __init__(Self, pos, gX, gY, gZ):
            wPos = pos
            Self.gmPos = intVec3(gX,gY,gZ)
            Self.checkedSpaces = {"white": [], "black": []}
            Self.model = Entity(model = "cube", scale = (125,100,125), position=Vec3(wPos.x, wPos.y, wPos.z), color=color.white, alpha=54, visible=False, PARENT = Self)
            Self.occupied = None
            Self.cntrSpot = Vec3(Self.model.x, Self.model.y-50, Self.model.z)
            Self.possOwner = None
            Self.model.on_mouse_enter = lambda: changeAlpha(Self.model, 120)
            Self.model.on_mouse_exit = lambda: changeAlpha(Self.model, 54)
            Self.model.on_click = None
        def spaceClicked(Self):
            if Self.possOwner != None:
                    newOwner = Self.possOwner
                    newOwner.pieceDeselect()
                    Self.possOwner = None
                    newOwner.move(Self)
                    Self.occupied = Self.possOwner
            else:
                print("no possOwner")#Condition should not ever happen

        def spaceSelect(Self, piece):
                Self.model.visible = True
                Self.possOwner = piece
                Self.model.color = color.green
                Self.model.alpha = (54)
                Self.model.collider = "box"
                Self.model.on_click = lambda: Self.spaceClicked()
        def spaceDeselect(Self):
                Self.model.collider = None
                Self.model.on_click = None
                Self.model.visible = False
                oPos = Self.possOwner.gmPos
                Self.possOwner = None
def knightMoves(gmPos):
        allPossMoves = []
        changes2 = [2, -2]
        changes1 = [1, -1]
        for I in changes2:
            for i in changes1:
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x+I,gmPos.y+i,gmPos.z))
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x+i,gmPos.y+I,gmPos.z))
        for I in changes2:
            for i in changes1:
                
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x,gmPos.y+I,gmPos.z+i))
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x,gmPos.y+i,gmPos.z+I))
        for I in changes2:
            for i in changes1:
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x+I,gmPos.y,gmPos.z+i))
                allPossMoves.append(intVec3(gmPos.x+i,gmPos.y,gmPos.z+I))
        return(allPossMoves)
def compileValidMoves(piece, gm):
        allPossMoves = []
        Type = piece.Type
        gmPos = piece.gmPos
        allPossMoves = knightMoves(gmPos)
        highlighted = []
        for I in allPossMoves:
                possSpace = gm.getSpace(I)
                if possSpace != None:
                        possSpace.spaceSelect(piece)
                        highlighted.append(possSpace)
        print("---------------")
        return highlighted
        
class Piece():
        def __init__(Self,gm, team, Type, ID, gmPos):
            Self.team = team
            Self.Type = Type
            Self.gm = gm #MaybeRemove
            Self.Space = None
            Self.model = Self.genModel()
            Self.selected = False
            Self.restricedMove = []
            Self.gmPos = gmPos
            Self.possMoves = []
            Self.ID = ID
            if gmPos.x !=-1 and gmPos.y !=-1 and gmPos.z != -1:
               Self.Space = gm.spaces[gmPos.x][gmPos.y][gmPos.z]
               Self.model.position = Self.Space.cntrSpot
               Self.Space.occupied = Self
                
            
        def genModel(Self):
                newModel = Entity(model=Self.gm.models.get(Self.Type),  scale = (1,1,1), size=(400,400),shader=lit_with_shadows_shader
                                ,collider="box", PARENT = Self)
                newModel.rotation_x -= 90
                if Self.team == "white":
                        newModel.color = color.white
                        Self.gm.whiteTeam.append(Self)
                else:
                        newModel.color = color.black
                        Self.gm.blackTeam.append(Self)
                newModel.collider.color=color.white
                newModel.collider.alpha=(54)
                newModel.on_click = lambda: Self.pieceClicked(Self.gm, Self)
                return(newModel)
        def move(Self, newSpace):
                print("Piece has been moved once")
                destroy(Self.model)
                Self.model = Self.genModel()
                Self.Space.occupied = None
                Self.Space = newSpace
                Self.model.position = newSpace.cntrSpot
                Self.gmPos = newSpace.gmPos
        def pieceDeselect(Self):
                Self.model.collider.visible = False
                Self.selected = False
                for I in Self.possMoves:
                        I.spaceDeselect()
                        
        def pieceSelect(Self, gm):
               #print(Self, " Space deselected")
               Self.model.collider.visible = True
               Self.selected = True
               Self.possMoves = compileValidMoves(Self, gm) 
        def pieceClicked(Self, gm, caller):
           print(caller)
           if Self.selected == True:
                Self.pieceDeselect()
           else:
               Self.pieceSelect(gm)
           

class GameSpace():
    def __init__(Self):
        Self.size = 1000
        Self.gmStartPos = (0-(Self.size/2), 0-(Self.size/2), 0-(Self.size/2))
        Self.models = {"king": "3DAssets\OBJ\King.obj", "knight": "3DAssets\OBJ\Knight.obj", "queen": "3DAssets\OBJ\Queen.obj",
              "rook": "3DAssets\OBJ\Rook.obj", "bishop": "3DAssets\OBJ\Bishop.obj", "pawn": "3DAssets\OBJ\Pawn.obj"}
        Self.whiteTeam = []
        Self.blackTeam = []
        Self.editorCamera = EditorCamera(enabled = False)
        Self.fPC = FirstPersonController(gravity = 0, speed = 0, grounded = False)
        Self.editorCamera = editorCamera = EditorCamera(enabled = False)
        Self.sqrLayers = []
        Self.spaces = []
        Self.testBlockCoolDown = 0
    def boardSetUp(Self):
        for I in range(8):
            pos = Vec3(0, (100*I)-400, 0)
            e = Entity(model=Grid(8,8), mode="line", thickness = 100, scale = (1000,1000,1000), position = pos)
            e.rotation_x += 90
            Self.sqrLayers.append(e)
        btmLeftStartPos = Vec3(Self.gmStartPos[0]+62.5, Self.gmStartPos[1]+150, Self.gmStartPos[2]+62.5)
        xChange = Vec3(btmLeftStartPos.x, btmLeftStartPos.y, btmLeftStartPos.z)
        for I in range(8):
                yChange = Vec3(xChange.x, xChange.y, xChange.z)
                Self.spaces.append([])
                for i in range(8):
                        zChange = Vec3(yChange.x, yChange.y, yChange.z)
                        Self.spaces[I].append([])
                        for j in range(8):
                             Self.spaces[I][i].append(Space(zChange, I, i, j))
                             zChange.z +=125
                        yChange.y+=100
                xChange.x+=125
    def getSpace(Self, pos):#Weird bug where - numbers wrap around
        if pos.x > -1 and pos.y > -1 and pos.z > -1:
                try:
                   return Self.spaces[pos.x][pos.y][pos.z]
                except:
                   pass
        return None
```

main

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from gameSetUpDEBUG import *

ttlFps = 0
numOfCounts = 0
app = Ursina(borderless = False, development_mode=True)

gm = GameSpace()
gm.boardSetUp()
Entity(model="sphere", position = gm.gmStartPos, color = color.blue, alpha = (54), scale=(50,50,50))
pieceNames = ["king", "queen", "bishop", "rook", "knight", "pawn",]
centerSquare = Entity(model="sphere", position = Vec3(-700,0,0), color = color.green, alpha = (54), scale=(50,50,50))
zPos = -300
newPiece = Piece(gm, "white", "king","K",intVec3(-1,-1,-1))
testPiece = Piece(gm, "black", "knight", "kn",intVec3(0,0,0))

def moveTo(toMove, pos, speed):
    toMove.world_x += pos.x*speed
    toMove.world_y += pos.y*speed
    toMove.world_z += pos.z*speed
speed = .5
debugBoolVar = False
count = intVec3(0,0,0) #continue
def update():
    gm.testBlockCoolDown -= 1
    if gm.fPC.enabled == True:
        if held_keys["w"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.forward, 4)
        if held_keys["s"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.back, 4)
        if held_keys["a"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.left, 4)
        if held_keys["d"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.right, 4)
        if held_keys["e"] or held_keys["spacebar"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.up, 4)
        if held_keys["q"]:
            moveTo(gm.fPC,gm.fPC.down, 4)
        if gm.testBlockCoolDown < 0:
            if held_keys["right mouse"]:
                if mouse.hovered_entity != None:
                    print(mouse.hovered_entity.PARENT)
                    print(mouse.world_point)
                    print(mouse.point)
                    Entity(model="sphere", position=mouse.hovered_entity, color=color.red, size=(100,100,100), scale=(10,10,10), alpha=58)
    
            if held_keys["up arrow"]==1:
                tbm.move(intVec3(0,1,0))
            if held_keys["down arrow"]==1:
               tbm.move(intVec3(0,-1,0))
            if held_keys["left arrow"]==1:
               tbm.move(intVec3(1,0,0))
            if held_keys["right arrow"]==1:
                tbm.move(intVec3(-1,0,0))
            if held_keys["o"]==1:
                tbm.move(intVec3(0,0,1))
            if held_keys["p"]==1:
                tbm.move(intVec3(0,0,-1))
            gm.testBlockCoolDown = 10
            if held_keys["v"]:
                global debugBoolVar
                if debugBoolVar == False:
                    print("Piece off")
                    gm.blackTeam[0].model.on_click = None
                    debugBoolVar = True
                else:
                    print("Piece on")
                    gm.blackTeam[0].model.on_click = lambda: gm.blackTeam[0].pieceClicked(gm, "piece")
                    debugBoolVar = False
def input(key):
    if key == "escape":
        quit()
    if key == "f up":
        if gm.fPC.enabled:
            gm.editorCamera.enabled  = True
            gm.fPC.enabled = False
        else:
            gm.fPC.enabled  = True
            gm.editorCamera.enabled = False
    
app.run()
```

I've tried debugging this so many different ways, I've tried tracing the functions calls back only to find they're being called as if code was running correctly, I've tried turning on and off the collider of the piece but somehow it can still be clicked by the spaces around it, I've even tried just printing out what the click raycast hits and where it hits, the weird thing about this approach is that the click raycast hits the piece but it can't say at what location it hit.

Output of the last approach mentioned above

```
<gameSetUpDEBUG.Piece object at 0x0000027B3E645B20> #print(mouse.hovered_entity.PARENT)
None                                                #print(mouse.world_point) 
None                                                #print(mouse.point)
```

Please let me know if that makes sense I've hardly ever used stack overflow and don't know if this is the correct way to format a question. Thanks in advance for any ideas!